# My flutter app crashes on start up when I include flutter_local_notifications in my pubspec.yaml file,what could be the issue?

Tags: flutter

am receiving this error when I run flutter run

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_local_notifications'.
```

Comment: is that the only error you got?

Comment: nop ,I received a very long list of errors but the platform wouldn't post since the text code ratio was off,most of them were fatal errors and all of them are saying content is not allowed on prolog eg [Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.71.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: You question is incomplete and it makes it very hard for people to provide you with an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried including version?

Try adding this code in your dependencies

```
dependencies:
   flutter_local_notifications: ^9.1.4
```

Comment: when I add it in the dependencies that's when the app crashes, when I remove it the app starts smoothly.I've tried including the version and removing the version but the app still crashes

Comment: yeah,i've tried that too